# how can assign a gameObject from code using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on random coin generator. I have included the code below:

```
timer -= Time.deltaTime;

if (timer <= 0)
{

    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(11f, 14f), Random.Range(-0.7f, 4.5f), 0);
    Instantiate(coins, position, transform.rotation);
    timer = delayTimer;
}
```

and I add a collision to pick the coin and make a score text:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Collisions : MonoBehaviour {
    public  Text scoreText;
    private float score;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        scoreText.text = "Score : " + score;



    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            scoreText.text = "Score : " + score;
            score++;

        }
    }

}
```

so now when I need to add the Text to the prefab I can't
and if I assign the text in somehow to the prefab it doesn't count any score

[image]

Comment: My guess: You kill your own game object and the execution of the script with the line `Destroy(gameObject);`, which is why it doesn't get to the `scoreText.text = ..` line anymore. Can you add a  `Debug.Log("Score changed to " + score);` line after chaning the score and watching the debug log output to confirm this? And second: `public  Text scoreText;` initializes the variable to `null`, so there is actually nothing to write to. You have to create a new `Text` object somewhere and add it to a canvas. Or is the `scoreText` supposed to be a static element in the scene?

Comment: when play the game i found this error 

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Collisions.Update () (at Assets/scripts/Collisions.cs:15)

Comment: Good, now you know that `scoreText` is always null inside the `Collisions` script. Now where is that `scoreText` supposed to come from? My guess is that it is a global object in the scene. Then you should find that `GameObject` in the scene with `var go = GameObject.Find("someName");` and then get the `Text` component of that with `var scoreText = go.GetComponent<Text>();`. And then you can edit the `.text` of that found `scoreText` object.

Comment: the script call RandomCoin "the Generator " is on empty gameOpject and i made a public gameOpject in the script to assign the coin   

and i delete the coin after make it prefab ; 
in the coin prefab i add the Collisions Scripts and inside the script i made a public Text in the script to assign the text Score  Ui .

now the problem that i need to assign the text from prefab witch for some reason i can't .. 
 now when i played the scene i have this error
 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Collisions.Update () (at Assets/scripts/Collisions.cs:15)

Comment: i don't need to assign a gameObject i just need to assign the text using the code instead of public text witch it deleted when transfer the coin to prefab

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt your guess is not valid. Destroy does not immediately destroy the gameobject. it waits for the end of frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a script or a prefab to know about a certain object in the scene. right?

Whenever you find yourself in this situation you must revise your approach. Keep in mind:

- **You can't assign a reference of an object from a scene to a prefab.** That's basically impossible. **prefabs aren't supposed to know about the scene.**
- You *can* assign a reference of an object from a scene to another object from the same scene.
- You *can* assign a reference of an object from (or within) a prefab to any object (either to another prefab or same prefab or within a prefab or to an object in the scene)

### In other words:

you can drag and drop anything anywhere except for *from scene to prefab*

### Alternative?

There are many.

Why not try singleton pattern? It's easy to learn and easy to use. It's impeccable with objects which *only have one instance*. Like a GameController or GuiController or a UserProfileController etc.

Having a singleton GuiController:

```
public class GuiController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //singleton setup
    static GuiController instance;
    void Awake() { instance = this; }

    //now it's ready for static calls

    public UnityEngine.UI.Text MyText;

    //static method which you can call from anywhere
    public static void SetMyText(string txt) { instance.MyText.text = txt; }
}
```

Have an object in the scene (better be the canvas). attach this script to it. Set the reference of `My Text` in it. In your collisions script just call `GuiController.SetMyText("Score : " + score)`

### Edit

There is actually a slight mistake with your Collision script.

the field `score` which is defined in `Collisions` resets to 0 in the new object every time a game object with this script is being instantiated. This happens because `score` is not defined as a static member of `Collisions` and any new object naturally has its own members i.e. a new score. In fact, it shouldn't be in `Collisions` it is better to have a GameController script handling these kinds of data.

Again with the singleton pattern:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    static GameController instance;
    void Awake() { instance = this; }

    float score;
    public static float Score { get { return instance.score; } set { instance.score = value; } }
}
```

Attach the script to a game object and instead of `score++` you can write `GameController.Score++`;

Comment: just like that GuiController.SetMyText(Nothing Here !!)

Comment: that was the lazy version of `GuiController.SetMyText("Score : " + score)`

Comment: i add it but the same .. :( 
i get a score : 0 but it doesn't change

Comment: are you sure the line you call the static method is being executed?

Comment: and you have a gameobject in the scene with GuiController script attached, and its 'my text' field is set to a Text object in the scene?

Comment: Hahha Okay , and Thanks for helping

Comment: the score should be a static so i change it and i have this problem 

StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.
GameController.get_Score () (at Assets/GameController.cs:9)

Comment: oops! sorry. it should have been `{ get { return score; } }` not `return Score`

Comment: thxx that's works for me but i have a new problem witch is the score isn't reset !!
i try to equal the Score with 0 but the counter no work any more ..

Comment: you may have to implement a reset method in it